# is the accept attribute compatible with all browsers?

Tags: html

Do all browsers support the `accept` attribute on `form` elements?

Comment: What `accept` attribute?

Comment: @BoltClock I guessed `accept-charset` attribute.

Comment: Don't use `accept-charset`. It's useless and even harmful. Just set charset in response content type header and use the same charset in server side to decode the submitted data.

Answer (score 1):

They all *accept* it (assuming you mean `accept-charset` attribute) but they don't all do the same thing with it.

> HTML forms may define the attribute accept-charset, which tells the browser which encoding to use when sending data to the server. The funny thing is, that it breaks horribly and is not handled properly by any browser.

[Further Reading (and browser handling)](http://kore-nordmann.de/blog/php_charset_encoding_FAQ.html#does-accept-charset-help-in-html-forms).

If you do use it, make sure it is the same as the charset you are delivering the document in. For example, if you have your document as `UTF-8`, your `accept-charset` attribute should be `UTF-8`.

Our lovely friend IE ignores the attribute altogether, though I'm not sure if that has been fixed in the *least worse* versions, e.g. IE9.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML, the input element, there is an [accept attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-accept). It does work in all browsers.